# MSSQL: IN with hardcoded value vs. IN with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-in

I have the following query:

```
SELECT c004, mesosafe, CAST(SUBSTRING (c000 ,1 , 5) as int) as sortorder, c001, c000, c002
FROM DE_DATA.dbo.t309
WHERE c001 IS NOT NULL
AND c002 = 1
AND mesocomp = 'EMTD'
AND mesoyear IN (
    SELECT MAX(mesoyear) AS currmesoyear
    FROM DE_DATA.dbo.t001
)
AND CAST(SUBSTRING (c000 ,1 , 5) as int) < 101
ORDER BY c000 ASC;
```

This query fails because some values of `c000` cannot be casted because they look like `008-` instead of `00052-`. Here the `mesoyear` is asked (mesoyear IN ...). If I query this SQL part alone I get `1344` as result.

On the other side this query works:

```
SELECT c004, mesosafe, CAST(SUBSTRING (c000 ,1 , 5) as int) as sortorder, c001, c000, c002
FROM DE_DATA.dbo.t309
WHERE c001 IS NOT NULL
AND c002 = 1
AND mesocomp = 'EMTD'
AND mesoyear IN (
    '1344'
)
AND CAST(SUBSTRING (c000 ,1 , 5) as int) < 101
ORDER BY c000 ASC;
```

So what is the difference between hardcoded values and the SQL query?

**Edit:**

I think the reason is that the subquery is evaluated later than the main query. Can it be? What can I do against this?

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming a certain order of execution, in as only certain rows you believe are 'correct' will be evaluated against the `CAST` operation. This is a fundamental fallacy. SQL is a declarative, set oriented language which does not make any evaluation ordering promise the way imperative languages do. As such your entire approach is flawed and you're asking the wrong question. Some query execution plans may work, some may fail, but those that work will start failing randomly later as the query chooses a different plan.

Ultimately your problem is the data model, the fact that you have to crack this composite `c000` field into substrings and cast to get out int values. Use string fields to store strings, use numeric fields to store numbers. Simple as that. What you're trying to achieve **will never work**.

See also [On SQL Server boolean operator short-circuit](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/) and [T-SQL Functions do not imply a certain order of execution](http://rusanu.com/2011/08/10/t-sql-functions-do-no-imply-a-certain-order-of-execution/).

Comment: You are right on my assumption. The system emerged over many years. It is now difficult to change these things on all places. Based on `mesoyear` I can distinct between old data (e.g. `008-`) and new data (e.g. `00052-`). Why is the whole data set been taken when the `mesoyear` should be only `1344`? Isn't there a simple solution to overcome this behavior?

Comment: See the examples in my two links. Both cases tried hard to overcome the problem and eventually failed. Both examples are drawn from real use experience. There is no way to force the query optimizer into generating a plan that guarantees the CAST occurs only on rows that match the `1344` condition. With SQL Server 2012 you can use [`TRY_CAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx) instead. With pre-2012 you can write your own SQLCLR casting function that silently swallows error input and returns NULL.

Comment: The one construct in T-SQL that does offer a evaluation order guarantee is [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).  So `WHERE CASE mesoyear WHEN '1344' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING (c000 ,1 , 5) as int) ELSE NULL END < 101` will not evaluate the `CAST` if the `mesoyear` is not `1344`. Pick your poison...

Comment: Even `CASE` isn't 100% guaranteed (trying to find some answers demonstrating this - I think it's Aaron Bertrand who's pulled me up on this before).

Comment: @Damien: true, constant folding can play nasty tricks to CASE... A error safe SQLCLR cast/parse function is much better

Answer (score 0):

Usually MsSql runs subqueries before their parent. You query *probably* fails when the inner query finds the first value it cannot cast to the same type-and-size of `mesoyear`. Did you check if columns `t309.mesoyear` and `t001.mesoyear` have the same type?

Nevertheless, there are some cases when MsSql doesn't follow the usual behaviour. If you think this is the case, consider using the [FORCE ORDER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) query hint (although this situation will eventually emerge again).

Last, but not least, if the CAST operator is not safe, you can (should) check if the value can be cast before incurring into a runtime error:

```
-- use
AND (1=1
  AND (ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(c000 ,1 , 5) = 1)
  AND (CAST(SUBSTRING (c000 ,1 , 5) as int) < 101)
)
-- instead of
AND CAST(SUBSTRING (c000 ,1 , 5) as int) < 101
```